# SQL Query, SELECT Top 2 by Foreign Key Order By Date

Tags: sql-server-2005, greatest-n-per-group, sql

I need a SQL query that returns the top 2 Plans by `PlanDate` per ClientID.  This is all on one table where `PlanID` is the PrimaryID, `ClientID` is a foreignID.

This is what I have so far -->

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tblPlan] 
WHERE [PlanID] IN (SELECT TOP (2) PlanID FROM [dbo].[tblPlan] ORDER BY [PlanDate] DESC)
```

This, obviously, only returns 2 records where I actually need up to 2 records per `ClientID`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT PlanId, ClientId, PlanDate FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY PlanDate DESC) rn, *
    FROM [dbo].[tblPlan]
) AS T1
WHERE rn <=2
```

Add any other columns you need to the select to get those too.

Answer (score 3):

Edit, Dec 2011. Corrected CROSS APPLY solution

Try both to see what is best

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( -- distinct ClientID values
   SELECT DISTINCT ClientID 
   FROM [dbo].[tblPlan]
  ) P1
  CROSS APPLY
  ( -- top 2 per ClientID 
   SELECT TOP (2) P2.PlanID
   FROM [dbo].[tblPlan] P2
   WHERE P1.ClientID = P2.ClientID
   ORDER BY P2.[PlanDate] DESC
  ) foo
```

Or

```
;WITH cTE AS (
  SELECT
     *,
     ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY [PlanDate] DESC) AS Ranking
  FROM
     [dbo].[tblPlan]
)
SELECT * FROM cTE WHERE Ranking <= 2
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks but I get this `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: my mistake, need alias on "applied" table

Comment: Interesting, your Second option and Mark Byers option each return 7062 rows.  Your first option returns 21948 rows.  Idea on the disparity?

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: fixed it (eventually!)